# Prove that $U=e^{i\alpha}R_{\hat{n}}(\beta)R_{\hat{m}}(\gamma)R_{\hat{n}}(\delta)$ for non-parallel unit vectors $\hat{m},\hat{n}$

Tags: linear-algebra, unitary-matrices, quantum-computation

> Suppose $\hat{m},\hat{n}$ are non-parallel real unit vectors in 3D. Show that an arbitrary single qubit unitary operator $U$ may be written as
> $$
> U=e^{i\alpha}R_{\hat{n}}(\beta)R_{\hat{m}}(\gamma)R_{\hat{n}}(\delta)
> $$
> for appropriate choices of $\alpha,\eta,\gamma,\delta$, where $R_{\hat{n}}(\theta)=\exp\Big(\frac{-i\theta}{2}\hat{n}.\vec{\sigma}\Big)=\cos(\theta/2)I-i(\hat{n}.\vec{\sigma})\sin(\theta/2)$, $\vec{\sigma}=(X,Y,Z)$, $X=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix},Y=\begin{bmatrix}0&-i\\i&0\end{bmatrix},Z=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}$ are Pauli matrices and $\hat{n}$ is some real 3D unit vector.

We can easily prove that $U=e^{i\alpha}R_{z}(\beta)R_{y}(\gamma)R_{z}(\delta)$ where $R_{x}(\theta)=\exp\Big(\frac{-i\theta}{2}X\Big)=\cos(\theta/2)I-i\sin(\theta/2)X=\begin{bmatrix}\cos\theta/2&-i\sin\theta/2\\-i\sin\theta/2&\cos\theta/2\end{bmatrix},R_{y}(\theta)=\exp\Big(\frac{-i\theta}{2}Y\Big)=\cos(\theta/2)I-i\sin(\theta/2)Y=\begin{bmatrix}\cos\theta/2&-\sin\theta/2\\\sin\theta/2&\cos\theta/2\end{bmatrix},R_{z}(\theta)=\exp\Big(\frac{-i\theta}{2}Z\Big)=\cos(\theta/2)I-i\sin(\theta/2)Z=\begin{bmatrix}e^{-i\theta/2}&0\\0&e^{i\theta/2}\end{bmatrix}$

My reference asks to prove $U=e^{i\alpha}R_{\hat{n}}(\beta)R_{\hat{m}}(\gamma)R_{\hat{n}}(\delta)$ from $U=e^{i\alpha'}R_{z}(\beta')R_{y}(\gamma')R_{z}(\delta')$ ?

Note: Please check [Page 176-Quantum Computation and Quantum Information Nielsen & Chuang](http://csis.pace.edu/%7Ectappert/cs837-19spring/QC-textbook.pdf)

**Attempt**

Thanks @BenGrossmann for the suggestion,

Since $R_{\hat{m}}(\theta)$ rotates a Bloch vector into any other Bloch vector which includes all possible qubit states upto a global phase factor, an arbitrary unitary operator can be written in the form $U=e^{i\alpha}R_{\hat{m}}(\theta)$

\begin{align}
U'=e^{ia}R_{\hat{m}}(t)=e^{ia}R_{z}(b)R_{y}(c)R_{z}(d)\\
\implies  R_{y}(c)=(R_{z}(b))^{-1}R_{\hat{m}}(t)(R_{z}(d))^{-1}\\
\boxed{R_{y}(c)=R_{z}(-b)R_{\hat{m}}(t)R_{z}(-d)}\tag{Eq.1}\\
\end{align}

It is easy to prove $U=e^{i\alpha}R_{z}(b')R_{y}(c')R_{z}(d')$ for real parameters $\alpha',b',c',d'$
$$
U=e^{i\alpha}R_{z}(b')R_{y}(c')R_{z}(d')=e^{i\alpha}R_{z}(b').R_{z}(-b)R_{\hat{m}}(t)R_{z}(-d).R_{z}(d')\\
=e^{i(\alpha)}R_{z}(b'-b)R_{\hat{m}}(t)R_{z}(d'-d)=e^{i(\alpha)}R_{z}(\beta)R_{\hat{m}}(\gamma)R_{z}(\delta)\\
$$
\begin{align}
\implies \boxed{U=e^{i(\alpha)}R_{\hat{m}}(\phi)=e^{i(\alpha)}R_{z}(\beta)R_{\hat{m}}(\gamma)R_{z}(\delta)=e^{i(\alpha')}R_{z}(\beta')R_{y}(\gamma')R_{z}(\delta')}\tag{Eq.2}
\end{align}

But, how do use this expression $U=e^{i(\alpha)}R_{z}(\beta)R_{\hat{m}}(\gamma)R_{z}(\delta)$ to reach $U=e^{i\alpha}R_{\hat{n}}(\beta)R_{\hat{m}}(\gamma)R_{\hat{n}}(\delta)$ ?

**My Attempt**

$U=e^{ik}R_{\hat{n}}(t)=e^{iq}R_{z}(b)R_{y}(c)R_{z}(d)\implies R_{\hat{n}}(t)=e^{i(q-k)}R_{z}(b)R_{y}(c)R_{z}(d)=e^{i a}R_{z}(b)R_{y}(c)R_{z}(d)$

$R_{\hat{n}}(\beta)=e^{i a}R_{z}(b)R_{y}(c)R_{z}(d)$ and $R_{\hat{n}}(\delta)=e^{i a'}R_{z}(b')R_{y}(c')R_{z}(d')$ and $R_{\hat{m}}(\gamma)=e^{i h}R_{z}(e)R_{y}(f)R_{z}(g)$.

$$
e^{i\alpha}R_{\hat{n}}(\beta)R_{\hat{m}}(\gamma)R_{\hat{n}}(\delta)=e^{i\alpha}e^{i a}R_{z}(b)R_{y}(c)R_{z}(d).R_{\hat{m}}(\gamma).e^{i a'}R_{z}(b')R_{y}(c')R_{z}(d')\\
=e^{i (\alpha+a+a')}R_{z}(b)R_{y}(c)R_{z}(d).R_{\hat{m}}(\gamma).R_{z}(b')R_{y}(c')R_{z}(d')\\
=e^{i (\alpha+a+a')}R_{z}(b).\big[R_{y}(c)R_{z}(d)R_{\hat{m}}(\gamma)R_{z}(b')R_{y}(c')\big].R_{z}(d')\\
=e^{i (\alpha')}R_{z}(b).\big[R_{y}(c)R_{z}(d)R_{\hat{m}}(\gamma)R_{z}(b')R_{y}(c')\big].R_{z}(d')
$$
From Eq.2, $R_{y}(c)R_{z}(d)R_{\hat{m}}(\gamma)R_{z}(b')R_{y}(c')=R_{y}(c)R_{\hat{n}}(\theta)R_{y}(c')$, which corresponds to rotating the frame about y-axis by $c'$, then rotate about the unit vector $\hat{n}$ by $\theta$ and rotate the frame about y axis by c, i.e., is some rotation about a unit vector $\hat{N}$ by some angle $\epsilon$

$\therefore$ $R_{y}(c)R_{z}(d)R_{\hat{m}}(\gamma)R_{z}(b')R_{y}(c')=R_{y}(c)R_{\hat{n}}(\theta)R_{y}(c')=R_{\hat{N}}(\epsilon)$
$$
e^{i\alpha}R_{\hat{n}}(\beta)R_{\hat{m}}(\gamma)R_{\hat{n}}(\delta)=e^{i (\alpha')}R_{z}(b).R_{\hat{N}}(\epsilon).R_{z}(d')\\
=e^{i (\alpha')}R_{\hat{r}}(\eta)=U
$$

i.e., Any unitary matrix $U=e^{i (\alpha')}R_{\hat{r}}(\eta)$ can be written as $e^{i\alpha}R_{\hat{n}}(\beta)R_{\hat{m}}(\gamma)R_{\hat{n}}(\delta)$ for some real numbers $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta$.

Comment: It might be helpful to first show that there exist $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta$ such that $U = e^{i\alpha} R_{\color{red}z}(\beta) R_{\hat m}(\gamma) R_{\color{red}z}(\delta)$ (where $\hat m$ is not parallel to $\hat z$) as an intermediate step.

Comment: Also, it would be helpful if you could share your reference (if possible)

Comment: @BenGrossmann Thanks for the response. I have tried to prove your suggestion $U=e^{i(\alpha)}R_{z}(\beta)R_{\hat{m}}(\gamma)R_{z}(\delta)$ and also added my reference in the post. Please check.

Comment: I think there's an issue with your approach. In particular, you use the fact that $R_{y}(c)=e^{i(a'')}R_{z}(-b)R_{\hat{m}}(t)R_{z}(-d)$ to conclude that $R_{y}(c')=e^{i(a'')}R_{z}(-b)R_{\hat{m}}(t)R_{z}(-d)$, which is not correct unless $c = c'$

Comment: Here's my initial attempt: There exist $\alpha_1,\beta_1,\gamma_1,\delta_1$ such that
$$
R_{\hat m}(\pi /2) = e^{i\alpha_1}R_z(\beta_1)R_y(\gamma_1)R_z(\delta_1).
$$
Because $\hat m$ is not a multiple of $z$, $\gamma$ is not a multiple of $\pi$.
$$
R_{\hat m}(\pi /2) = e^{i\alpha_1}R_z(\beta_1)R_y(\gamma_1)R_z(\delta_1) \implies\\
-i \hat m \cdot \sigma = 
e^{i\alpha_1}R_z(\beta_1)(\cos \gamma_1 I - i\sin \gamma_1 Y)R_z(\delta_1) \implies\\
Y = \csc \gamma_1R_z(-\beta_1)(-i \hat m \cdot \sigma)R_z(-\delta_1)
- i \cot\gamma_1  R_z(\beta_1 + \delta_1)
$$

Comment: With that, I suspect you could get an expression for $R_y(c)$ in the form $R_z(p)R_{\hat m}(q) R_z(r)$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann I used the fact that any unitary operator can be written as $U'=e^{i\alpha'}R_{\hat{m}}(t)$ which I equated to $e^{ia}R_{z}(b)R_{y}(c)R_{z}(d)\implies R_{y}(c)=e^{i(a'')}R_{z}(-b)R_{\hat{m}}(t)R_{z}(-d)$. But, why do I need the condition $c=c'$ ?

Comment: Oh, I thought that the two values of $t$ were supposed to be the same.  You seem to be assuming, then, that because there exist $a'',b,c,d$ such that $R_{y}(c)=e^{i(a'')}R_{z}(-b)R_{\hat{m}}(t)R_{z}(-d)$ for any value of $t$, there must exist $a'',b,t,d$ such that $R_{y}(c)=e^{i(a'')}R_{z}(-b)R_{\hat{m}}(t)R_{z}(-d)$ for any value of $c$. I think this requires some kind of proof.

Comment: @BenGrossmann I have made few edits, is it the proof sufficient now ?. First step we proved $R_{y}(c')=e^{i(a'')}R_{z}(-b)R_{\hat{m}}(t)R_{z}(-d)$ for some real parameters $a'',c',b,d$ then we substitute this into $U=e^{i\alpha'}R_{z}(b')R_{y}(c')R_{z}(d')$ for $R_{y}(c')$ and obtained the expression $U=e^{i(\alpha'+a'')}R_{z}(b'-b)R_{\hat{m}}(t)R_{z}(d'-d)=e^{i(\alpha)}R_{z}(\beta)R_{\hat{m}}(\gamma)R_{z}(\delta)$, is it not a complete proof?

Comment: @BenGrossmann I have tried to find a proof in "My Attempt" section starting from your suggestion of the intermediate step. Could you please comment on that.